# Problems with includes when migrating to experimental gradle Android Studio 2.0+

Tags: c, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, libusb, android-studio-2.0

My problem goes beyond of what the title says so will give a background before the question. I've been experimenting issues since I updated from Android Studio 1.5 to 2.0 (now using 2.1.1 Stable, tried beta version as well)

**Background**

When I updated my Android Studio and opened c files in NDK y started receiving the following message:
[image: sync gradle message]
This message appears even though I have already synced the project.

The compiler was working fine, as I could ignore modify things in c and it would still compile. Then I tried to add a new include of a file created by me which contains some settings and methods, the same file is included in other files working well. However, this time the compiler throws me the following error:

```
error: undefined reference to 'my_method'
```

Spent quite a while debugging but was unsuccessful, so decided to migrate to experimental gradle where this problem does not happen.

Here is what I'm using now:
- gradle-experimental:0.7.0
- wraper: gradle-2.10-all.zip

My gradle file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "com.domain.myapp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }

        task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
            } 
        }
    }
    task runSwig(type: Exec, description: 'Run swig config') {
        workingDir 'src/main'
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'swig.bat'
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName "MyNativeModule"
        //toolchain "clang"
    }

    sources.main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs
                srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
            versionNameSuffix "1.0"
        }        
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'    
    compile 'org.litepal.android:core:1.2.1'
}
```

Now, when I run clean it finishes successfully, but..

**Now the problem:**

*I'm using a libusb library
When I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
-Error:(20, 20) config.h: No such file or directory
-Error:(33, 30) libkern/OSAtomic.h: No such file or directory
-Error:(29, 25) dev/usb/usb.h: No such file or directory
... many others like these
```

In the case of config.h in the library it's included like this:

```
#include <config.h>
```

so since I have that file in a parent directory in the library, I managed to make it work this way:

```
#include "../config.h>
```

On the other hand for the other files, I don't have the directories nor the files in the library so I cannot reference them. Besides, I see these files belong to MacOS when I google them.

With standard gradle this is not a problem as it compiles like a charm!

**My questions are:**

- Why is this happening? is there some compilation flag I'm missing to ignore these files?
- How can I fix this issue, what would be the best approach?

**What I've already tried:**

- Update NDK from 11 to 12
- Switch from stable Android Studio to Beta channel and back
- Tried different gradle versions stable and experimental

As I'm getting familiar with NDK and C my question might be to obvios, any help will be much appreciated!

**Update**

I'm building libusb library as I made some changes to it. (with stable gradle this works fine except for the problem I described above, before the update I have been using this setup for a few months, everything working as expected)

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-jni
-jni/myUSB/libusb
```

Here are my Android.mk files so you see how I'm building them:
jni:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOT_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := myModuleName
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
jiw.cpp \
mainFile.c \
otherFile.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := myUSB
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

myUSB:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOTUSB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOTUSB_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := myUSB
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -pthread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
myUsbMainFile.c \
myUsbInterface.c \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/ 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := android-usb
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

libusb:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := android-usb
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
core.c \
descriptor.c \
io.c \
sync.c \
os/linux_usbfs.c \
os/threads_posix.c \
os/android_java.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/os
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: typically, we switch to *experimental* plugin to get rid of `ndk-build`. If you want to use the **ndkBuild** task, you need different dependencies set in your **build.gradle**. If you want the *experimental* plugin to build the C/C++ library for you, you should point `jni { source { srcDir` to the directory that contains the source files, and probably add more statements to `ndk {` block.

Comment: I'm  not familiar with experimental plugin, so didn't know you typically use it to get rid of the ndk-build, I will definitely look this up. If you have a source where I can read more about this I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: this is the official website for the gradle-experimental plugin, containing gradle DSL changes and native build configuration examples: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental
you might be especially interested in chapter 5 "NDK integration" http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Ndk-Integration

Answer (score 0):

I can't see, where you connect **libusb** to your project. So, you probably have to link it manually. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ph0b/418132cb2f3f03a5534c) is an example, how to link libraries statically/dynamically in build.gradle.

Comment: I have updated my question, with my Android.mk files, I have made changes to libusb so I'm actually building the library.